# amsbook subfigure numberings are always upper case

Tags: subfloats, labels, amsbook

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!tb]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \bullet
        \end{tikzcd}
        \caption{label 1}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzcd}
            \bullet
        \end{tikzcd}
        \caption{label 2}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: label 1 and label 2]

Despite the fact that I used `\alph`, the label numberings appear in upper case. Is this due to the fact that `amsbook` handles subfigures in a different way? How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font of the captions in `amsbook` is defined to be `scshape`. A workaround is to add this to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@captionheadfont{}
\makeatother
```

The default in `amsbook` is `\def\@captionheadfont{\scshape}`.